# javascript templating engine that matches the smarty syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, smarty

I am looking for a client-side javascript templating engine that matches the smarty syntax. We will probably use jQuery with it. Since we have a lot of legacy smarty templates, I am looking for an engine that we can feed with the old templates. The minimum would be to have the same placeholder syntax, but the closer the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Smarty implementation in JavaScript:

https://github.com/balupton/jquery-smarty

Comment: excellent. Did you use it ? I need to make sure it is reliable

Comment: No, I just read about it in another SO question a few days ago. Simply test you app or parts of it with this engine - that'll probably be less work than rewriting all your templates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Free and open-source port of PHP Smarty to JScript: http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/